# How to replace this code in r by a function?

Tags: r, function

I have this code that works but I would like to learn how to replace it by a function.

```
library(tidyverse)

l1_1617 <- read.csv("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1617/F1.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
l1_1516 <- read.csv("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1516/F1.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
l1_1415 <- read.csv("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1415/F1.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
l1_1314 <- read.csv("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1314/F1.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

l1_1617_sel <- l1_1617 %>%
  select(Date:AST) %>%
  mutate(season = 1617)

l1_1516_sel <- l1_1516 %>%
  select(Date:AST) %>%
  mutate(season = 1516)

l1_1415_sel <- l1_1415 %>%
  select(Date:AST) %>%
  mutate(season = 1415)

l1_1314_sel <- l1_1314 %>%
  select(Date:AST) %>%
  mutate(season = 1314)


l1_1317 <- bind_rows(l1_1617_sel, l1_1516_sel, l1_1415_sel, l1_1314_sel)
```

For the first step I have tried something like this but it obviously failed:

```
dl_l1 <-function(x){
  df_x <- read.csv("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/x/F1.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}

dl_l1(1617)
```

Comment: Are you using a package that you have not declared? I get: `Error in l1_1617 %>% select(Date:AST) %>% mutate(season = 1617) : 
  could not find function "%>%"
`
`

Comment: Sorry, just corrected it.

Comment: Did the answer help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `paste` to concatenate to build the url. Below code should work.

```
dl_l1 <-function(x){
  read.csv(paste0("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/",x,"/F1.csv"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
    select(Date:AST) %>%
    mutate(season = x)
}

dl_l1(1617)

#final output

l1_1317 <- bind_rows(dl_l1(1617), dl_l1(1516), dl_l1(1415), dl_l1(1314))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)

ids <- as.character(c(1617, 1516, 1415, 1314))

data <- lapply(ids, function(i) {

  read.csv(paste0("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/", i ,"/F1.csv"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
    select(Date:AST) %>%
    mutate(season = i)

})

data <- do.call(rbind, data)
```

Comment: Really interesting. Is there a way to replace the use of lapply by a function from the tidyverse? Btw a bracket is missing for you "ids" vector.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, thanks for highlighting it, corrected it. I am not very familiar with the full functionality in `tidyverse`, but I think you should have a look at `map()`. Check the documentation on loops in [tidyverse](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html#the-map-functions).

Answer (score 0):

I would create a for loop in a function so you can iterate through a vector of numbers:

create function `football` that takes a number, or a vector of numbers, then create an empty `data.frame`. for each number in the vector, you want to paste it into the url, and then `mutate` the year into that `df`. Then you bind_rows into the `df`. At the end you return the football_df which is the bind_rows version of all of the ones combined.

```
library(dplyr)

football <- function(numbers){
  football_df <- data.frame()

  for (i in seq_along(numbers)){
    df <- read.csv(paste("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/",numbers[i],"/F1.csv", sep=""), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
      mutate(year = numbers[i])
    football_df <- bind_rows(football_df, df)
  }
  return(football_df)

}


years <- c(1617, 1415, 1314)

final_df <- football(years)
```

Comment: Just a side note concerning speed. The solution works, however, growing your `data.frame` within the loop slows it down. You can speed it up by initializing the `data.frame` with number of rows equal to the number of items in numbers. Try the package `microbenchmark` to compare the difference. For small data sets this does not really matter, but for larger ones, this might be important.

Comment: Good call, thanks for the note. Your `lapply` solution is better.

Comment: Depending on your data and how complex the final output should look or what kind of referencing is necessary a for loop can still make sense. I highly recommend a look into [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/) by [Hadley Wickham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16632/hadley) which discusses this issue (beside many other interesting things).